# LVM move logical volumes across physical volumes without data loss

Tags: linux, lvm, move

I wonder how can I move my logical volumes from current physical volume to another without data loss.  I have read mans but I haven't found this information there.
I would be grateful for any help. Thx in advance

Answer (score 2):

command is pretty straightforward

```
 pvmove /dev/sdb /dev/sdc
```

where

- /dev/sdb is source
- /dev/sdc is destination

those volume need to be in vg.

This command will remove from sdb all logical volume (provided there is room in /dev/sdc)

you can latre issue a

```
vgreduce vg01 /dev/sdb
```

to remove sdb from vg01.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to free a specific disk - you can use
`pvmove /dev/sdb`
It will spread the data among all other disk of the vg.

There are lots of cammands under the `lvm` tool. If you specify your goal the answer will be more helpful